# cx_Oracle connection with Pyinstaller export to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, cx-oracle

I am trying to use Pyinstaller to bundle an exe file from a script that creates a tkinter gui which collects data from an Oracle database using cx_Oracle. The script executes without error when run in python but the exe gives the following error.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
  File "report_gui.py", line 127, in <lambda>
  File "report_gui.py", line 63, in run_from_gui
  File "run_reports.py", line 52, in run_rpts
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1072: the Oracle Client library version is unsupported
```

I've found a few threads detailing similar issues but I get the same error after implementing their suggestions, namely the answer from Al Nazari in this thread [How to bundle cx_oracle with Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603905/how-to-bundle-cx-oracle-with-pyinstaller) as well as this page https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2014-December/103608.html . Both are years old, though so I'm wondering if recent updates have changed things. I'm running Python 3.9, Pyinstaller 4.5.1 and Oracle instant client 19.11. This is my .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['report_gui.py'],
             pathex=['.\'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['babel.numbers'],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries + [('oraociei19.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\oraociei19.dll','BINARY')] + 
[('oci.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\oci.dll','BINARY')] +
[('ocijdbc19.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\ocijdbc19.dll','BINARY')] +
[('ociw32.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\ociw32.dll','BINARY')] +
[('oramysql19.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\oramysql19.dll','BINARY')] +
[('orannzsbb19.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\orannzsbb19.dll','BINARY')] +
[('oraocci19.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\oraocci19.dll','BINARY')] +
[('oraocci19d.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\oraocci19d.dll','BINARY')] +
[('oraons.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\oraons.dll','BINARY')] +
[('orasql19.dll','.\instantclient_19_11\orasql19.dll','BINARY')],
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='report_gui',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None , icon='logo.ico')
```

The people that need to use this app will have Oracle client but not python. I've never used Pyinstaller before so it's possible I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: If the problem isn't in `tkinter` can you please remove the `tkinter` tag?

Comment: Does the destination machine have the VS redistributable needed by Instant Client?  Is some other (older) Oracle client software on the machine being used?

Comment: Yes. Actually, the executable works on my coworkers' computers, only not mine so far. I work with Oracle client most, so I wonder if my version is too new and not compatible? Regardless, the issue isn't pressing anymore. Thanks :)